# Python to sort individual words into alphabetical + corresponding translations in columns

Tags: python

So, this is the script that has very kindly been given to me as a starter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import with_statement    # needed for Python 2.5
from itertools import chain

def chunk(s):
    """Split a string on whitespace or hyphens"""
    return chain(*(c.split("-") for c in s.split()))

def process(latin, gloss, trans):
    chunks = zip(chunk(latin), chunk(gloss))
    # now you have to DO SOMETHING with the chunks!

def main():
    with open("examples.txt") as inf:
        try:
            while True:
                latin = inf.next().strip()
                gloss = inf.next().strip()
                trans = inf.next().strip()
                process(latin, gloss, trans)
                inf.next()    # skip blank line
        except StopIteration:
            # reached end of file
            pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

However,

I've just spoken to my lecturer, who has let me know that he doesn't want us using the

```
__ x __
```

function, as it is "too advanced for the students' needs at this point in the course".
I'm absolutely stumped as to what I need to put into the "chunks" or "process" fields, up until now I've been able to figure most of the other exercises out (with a few hints) but this one is just way beyond me. This particular part is worth 15 points out of 20, and it's making me feel just a little bit sick!
Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Original post** (sorry it's so long!)

I'm trying to do the following: I have a text with a language other than english, broken up into morphemes (parts of each word) using hyphens, with the English gloss (linguistic translation of each morpheme) and a direct translation below. eg.

> Itali-am fat-o profug-us Lavini-a-que ven-it
>
> Italy-Fem:Sg:Acc fate-Neut:Sg:Abl fleeing-Masc:Sg:Nom Lavinian-Neut:Pl:Acc come:Perf-3-Sg:Indic:Act
>
> 'in flight [driven] by fate came to Italy and the Lavinian [shores]'

I'll have several texts such as the above in one file - i.e.

```
blank line

a line of latin broken up with hyphens

a line of gloss broken up with corresponding hyphens, using colons to join elements

a line of translation

blank line

latin

gloss

translation

ad infinitum.
```

What I need to do is write a file that gives me the following output:

```
Itali:    1    Italy
am:    1    Fem:Sg:Acc
fat:    1    fate
o:    1    Neut:Sg:Abl
profug:   1    fleeing
us:    1    Masc:Sg:Nom
Lavini:    1    Lavinian
a:    1    Neug:Pl:Acc
que:    1    come:Perf
ven:    1   3
it:     1   Sg:Indic:Act
```

where the first column represents the first line of text without hyphens; the second column indicates the number of occurrences (it's only 1 each in this example), and the third column is the English translation of the first column, as written in the text.

If there's a latin morpheme with no corresponding English gloss/translation, the Latin column will be as normal but the English column will print [unknown], like:

```
a:  1   [unknown]
```

And if the opposite, i.e. an English morpheme with no corresponding Latin, it should print

```
[unknown]:  1   kitten
```

Finally, the prog needs to be able to deal with homophonous morphemes (i.e. two identically spelled latin morphemes with different meanings). e.g.

```
a:  16  Neuter:Plural
a:  28  Feminine:Singular
```

Comment: the function that looks like this: /__name__ (but without the /)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to count occurrences, you need a dictonary.

Create a dictionary where the key is the tuple generated by zip, and the value is a list that has: [latin, amount, translation].  Each time you encounter the same tuple you increment the amount.

The dictionary has to outlive the function so you probably want to add it as a parameter.

Once you are done, you can do: result = dict.keys(); result.sort().

I'm not sure I understand the part of the unknowns.  If this does not solve that part, you might need to show a relevant example.